# Is there an elegant way to start a foreach from the second index and then do the rest?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

If I have the following:

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo $v;
}
```

How can I make it output:

```
2, 1, 3, 17
```

Comment: Is there a good purpose for doing that?  Why not declare the array in the order you want it to be?

Comment: It's the order I get from the database query. Hmm, maybe I should be asking in the mysql section?

Comment: What *ordering rules* would order the output as desired? - I can't see one except for "if value is 'two'". And without rules, there is no sorting ..

Comment: @user2864740: That is basically the situation I'm in.

Comment: `.. ORDER BY IF(key = 'two', 0, 1), value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Language Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

$b = array_values($a);
echo implode(', ', array($b[1], $b[0]) + $b), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2, 1, 3, 17
```

Comment: I like this simplicity, however, + $b should probably be + array_slice($b, 2), else it would out put 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 17.

Comment: Thanks and well, it would not. Any right-hand key that already exists in the left-hand array will be ignored when adding arrays in PHP. The output shown is what you will get if you run the code. It is a bit weird, but hey it's PHP after all... :P

Comment: It works, I like how PHP has these interesting things you can do if you read the manual.  There are tons of array features that can make working with them effortless.

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array_values($a);
echo "{$values[1]}, {$values[0]}, "
foreach (array_slice($values, 2) as $v){
    echo "$v, "
}
```

If you care about last comma...

```
$values = array_values($a);
echo "{$values[1]}, {$values[0]}, "
$lastIndex = count($values) - 1;

foreach (array_slice($values, 2) as $k => $v){
    echo $v;
    if ($k != $lastIndex){
        echo ", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like:

```
<?php

$my_array = array(...); 

$keys = array_keys($my_array);
$second_key = $keys[1]; // if your array can be whatever size, probably want to check that first

echo $my_array[$second_key];

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == $second_key) {
    continue;
  }

  echo $value;
}

?>
```